# Disable/Enable input:date on checkbox click doen't work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable the Date field on uncheck checkbox and vice-versa.

http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsSakthi/ZKw9x/2/

Also this works differently in different browsers!

```
$('#certExpiry').click(function(){
if($('#certExpiry').is(':checked')){
    alert('checked');
    $('#expiryDate').removeProp('disabled');
}
else
    alert('uncheck');
    $('#expiryDate').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this...

```
$('#certExpiry').click(function () {
    $('#expiryDate').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lz7S/).

Also, don't use [`removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) like that. The documentation makes this clear...

> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as
>   `checked`, `disabled`, or `selected`. This will remove the property
>   completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use
>   `.prop()` to set these properties to `false` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put your `else` code in brackets `{}`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKw9x/4/